# How to use reachabilityWithHostName in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I'm trying to use the `reachabilityWithHostName` to test the server connection for the purpose of recognise whether "*the server is down or not reachable*".

However, there is an error:

> '`reachabilityWithHostName`' is unavailable: use object construction '`Reachability(hostName:)`'

Swift:

```
     let _HOST = "www.google.com" as NSString
     var netReach: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityWithHostName(_HOST)
     var netStatus: NetworkStatus = netReach.currentReachabilityStatus()
        if (netStatus.value==ReachableViaWiFi.value) {

        } else if(netStatus.value==ReachableViaWWAN.value) {

        } else {
            println("notreachable")
        }
```

How can I use the function `reachabilityWithHostName`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
let _HOST = "www.google.com" as NSString
var netReach: Reachability = Reachability(hostName:_HOST)
```

Comment: i think it is work, but there is another error occur :'NetworkStatus' is not convertible to 'NSObject'. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: after edit from `netStatus==ReachableViaWWAN` to `netStatus.value==ReachableViaWWAN.value` which is work fine, thank you very much